# Vaadin Framework for statistical analysis

Tags: java, vaadin, server-side

I want to write a java Web-App (Server-Side) using the Vaadin framework. The Web-App should interact with a database, parse some data and print out some statistical analysis. 
Is the statistical analysis part of data included in the standard vaadin framework, or is it part of the "Pro Tools" they offer for purchase? 
I would have gone directly to Vaadin with this, but they're down for maintenance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll code your statistical analysis part with plain Java, possibly some Java libraries that can help you there and possibly with bit of DB power as well. The UI part to run the analysis and showing the results is built with Vaadin. If you want to visualise the results, Vaadin Charts (part of "Pro Tools") is the most advanced solution available, but the are many open source charting solutions available as well via vaadin.com/directory.